# Mathematics equivalent of Feynman's Lectures in Physics?

Tags: soft-question, textbook-recommendation

I'm looking for an equivalent of "Feynman's Lectures in Physics" in mathematics. I'm specifically looking for book/books that delve into, using Feynman's words, "the meaning of things".

Comment: I've actually watched some of his lectures on youtube.i doubt there is anyone close to him on this matter in math but here is a few off of. My watch list:(general talks about math)

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8hgsKAm8HcA

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=h4jVZatICAo

Comment: In my opinion "meaning of things" in Mathematics has a much broad sense than in Physics (where it essentially means "explaination of natural phenomena"). So it is very difficult (if not impossible) to write a treatise in the spirit of Feyman's

Comment: Indeed, in his usual provocative style, he used to say "Physics is to sex as Mathematics is to masturbation" 
:-)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi The great Feynman was sometimes wrong!

Comment: @Todd Trimble: I never said I'm agreeing with him :-)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I didn't think you were. I just had to register my own disagreement. :-)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi So its "I'm having a headache" vs. "At least one of us has fun" ?

Comment: Oh Johannes, how delightfully ambiguous you are!

Comment: I have no idea of what can be the meaning of "the meaning of things" in mathematics. From one point of view the book by Courant and Robbins recommended in the answer below is a good choice, as well as Rademacher-Toeplitz, but both are much more elementary that Feynman's lectures (Hardy-Wright may be similar in level to Feynman's, but it is restricted to Number Theory). From another (very different) point of view some books from Bourbaki (and Bourbaki's componets)  can be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11):

since you ask specifically about "the meaning of things", this might be what you are looking for:

[What Is Mathematics? An Elementary Approach to Ideas and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195105192)

> For more than two thousand years a familiarity with mathematics has
>   been regarded as an indispensable part of the intellectual equipment
>   of every cultured person. Today, unfortunately, the traditional place
>   of mathematics in education is in grave danger. The teaching and
>   learning of mathematics has degenerated into the realm of rote
>   memorization, the outcome of which leads to satisfactory formal
>   ability but does not lead to real understanding or to greater
>   intellectual independence. This new edition of Richard Courant's and
>   Herbert Robbins's classic work seeks to address this problem. Its goal
>   is to *put the **meaning** back into mathematics*.
>
> Formal mathematics is like spelling and grammar--a matter of the
>   correct application of local rules. Meaningful mathematics is like
>   journalism--it tells an interesting story. But unlike some journalism,
>   the story has to be true. The best mathematics is like literature--it
>   brings a story to life before your eyes and involves you in it,
>   intellectually and emotionally. What is Mathematics is like a fine
>   piece of literature--it opens a window onto the world of mathematics
>   for anyone interested to view.